# Handling streaming logs in c#, richtextbox too slow

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, richtextbox

I have a client app in c# winforms that, among other tasks, receives real time logs from another app over a tcp socket. If I just add the log text to a richtextbox, the application is quickly bogged down. Obviously the user can't read text at the rate its coming in, but we have to ability to stop and start the system so we can look back through the logs.
Is there a better choice than richtextbox? I would like to retain the ability to color text and the ability to scroll back through the log. Would something in WPF work better?

Comment: Did you try profiling to ensure the rich textbox is really the bottleneck?

Comment: If the user can't read it, why bother putting it on the screen anyway? Why not output to a log file?

Comment: @DavidB I dont want the user to have to go load separate files, this should be quickly available. Is there a simple way to have the log file associated with a control that can scroll through it while its updated? Its hard to believe c# cant do this since simple shells handle the log volume fine.

Comment: @user511670 If you're creating the log file, you don't need the user to select anything. Dump the log to a file, and when the user wants to view it, load it back up and put it in your textbox. There's no point in realtime updating if your user doesn't want it and can't read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add all the lines to a List which can look something like this:

```
public class LogLine
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

 List<LogLine> _log = new List<LogLine>(5000);
```

and use a control which supports virtualization to display the LogLines. You can also create your own by using for example 10 Labels/TextBlocks which you manually assign values from the List based on scrollposition. 
The solution will eat memory if you let the list grow unlimited. If you need huge logs, you should use the filesystem to save data and truncate the list periodically.